# Additional path prefix on drupal 7

Tags: url, drupal, path

I have to build a multilingual website where you have to select your continent.

So you can choose America while your are in English but also America in Spanish. Europe in French, but also in English etc.

I have set language detection with path prefix on drupal 7. So my urls are like that **domain.com/en/path-alias**.

Some contents on my website will be hide for some continent but a lot of content will be the same so I dont want to do a multisite.

I wish to have urls like that **domain.com/america/en/path-alias**, **domain.com/america/es/path-alias** or **domain.com/europe/fr/path-alias**.
I don't find any solution to do that.

The module domain access looks cool but is not exactly what i want cause it works with subdomains while i want path prefix.

**EDIT :**
Ok i have found the solution of my problem in the drupal API.

This two hooks are exactly what i was looking for [hook_url_inbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this 2 hooks because in `hook_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language)` you tell Drupal what path should it display, and determine from received path that comes in `$original_path` (ex: *region/lang/path*) path that Drupal understands as a valid path (ex: *lang/path*) and override `$path` with it.

Next we need links from our pages to contain our custom path format, so we'll use `hook_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path)` to convert all system paths or aliases generated with `url()` in your custom path format (generated path for `url('lang/path'))` will be *region/lang/path*. In `$options` array we can modify path prefix, or path language.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but path alias dose not working now. This http://localhost/en/australia/node/376 should be http://localhost/en/australia/hotels-resorts

```
function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language){    
  $cluster = 'australia';
  $path = str_replace($cluster.'/','',$path);       
} 

function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path){
  $cluster = 'australia';   
  $path = $cluster.'/'.($path); 
  $options['alias'] = true;     
}
```